# Python calling robocopy to copy from a single source into multiple destinations

Tags: python

So I have seen many examples of copying from multiple directories into a single one and the use of a batch file to copy into multiple directories. I am trying to copy a source folder contents into destination folders all on the same server using python and robocopy. I would like to make the process a bit more automated than typing each line (like below) with the same source and the different destinations? What would be the best way to tackle this? I have tried wrapping in a for loop however I get the following error:

TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not list

```
subprocess.call(["robocopy", source_directory, destination_directory])
subprocess.call(["robocopy", source_directory, destination_directory2])
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
source_directory = os.path.join("") 
destination_directories = [os.path.join(source_directory, ""), os.path.join(source_directory, "")] 
for dest in destination_directories: 
     shutil.copy(source_directory, destination_directories)
```

Error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last): 
 File ".../Documents/Python_Scripts/test.py", 
   line 25, in <module> shutil.copy(source_directory, destination_directories) 
 File "...\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\shutil.py", 
   line 413, in copy if os.path.isdir(dst): 
 File "...AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\genericpath.py", 
   line 42, in isdir st = os.stat(s) 
 TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not list
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There ae other useful information.

Comment: it seems `path` is list with many elements and you have to use index to get single element from list - ie. `stat( path[0] )` - or you should use `for`-loop - ie. `for item in path: stat( item )`

Comment: Apologies on the lack of detail for the error. There have been a lot today with trying different ways to tackle this.
This is one of the ways I tried to approach it. I have also tried creating a list of the directories but receive a similar error.
source_directory =  os.path.join("")
destination_directories = [os.path.join(source_directory, ""), 
os.path.join(source_directory, "")]

for dest in destination_directories:
    shutil.copy(source_directory, destination_directories)

Comment: This is the full error with some personal items removed.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../Documents/Python_Scripts/test.py", line 25, in <module>
    shutil.copy(source_directory, destination_directories)
  File "...\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\shutil.py", line 413, in copy
    if os.path.isdir(dst):
  File "...AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\genericpath.py", line 42, in isdir
    st = os.stat(s)
TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not list

Comment: always put in question (not in comment) - it will be more readable and more people will see it - and maybe someone else will have idea for solution.

Comment: You have to use `dest` instead of `destination_directories` in `shutil.copy(source_directory, dest)`

Answer (score 0):

It it very primitive problem - use `dest` instead of `destination_directories` in `copy()`

```
for dest in destination_directories: 
     #shutil.copy(source_directory, destination_directories) # ERROR
     shutil.copy(source_directory, dest)
```

---

if you use `print(dest)` and `print(destination_directories)` then you will see difference.

Comment: Thats really good to hear and got me over a hurdle though it seems shutil doesn't have the right perms to be able to copy files in windows so looking at robocopy now. Trying to use similar code:

destination_directories = [os.path.join(source_directory, "D:\...\DevOps\PythonScripts\destination"), 
os.path.join(source_directory, "D:\...\DevOps\PythonScripts\destination1")]

for dest in destination_directories:
    from subprocess import call
    call(["robocopy",source_directory, dest])

The new error is too long to post but

Comment: So I changed to robocopy and added an extra \ to my path as I was getting a TypeError: bufsize must be an integer.

The copy was a success into two directories though it also created the folders inside the destination so I will have to mess with it. 

Appreciate your patience as I am definitely still learning